# How can display the image of the current element that you click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/rtcydtyh/6/)

For example, when I click on div element 1 in the ".dreapta" to put the image and click on the item paragraful.Daca is two to hide one element and so ...

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul>

    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/images-50x50.png"width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 1</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://whyfiles.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/promega_logo.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 2</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://bikechicago.com/wp-content/uploads/bikechicago-uber-image-C2.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 3</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://coordinate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/CBR_Web_Images.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 4</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://www.bpifrance-lelab.fr/var/bpi/storage/images/media/images/image-couverture/34625-1-fre-FR/image-couverture_large.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 5</p>
    </li>
    <li id="#bar">
        <img src="http://odpiralnicasi.com/photos/012/539/image-big.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 6</p>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="dreapta">

</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:95px;
    float:left;
}

ul li{border-bottom:1px solid;}

p{padding;0;margin:0;}

.dreapta{float:right;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$("ul li").click(function (event) {
    var barIndex = $("ul li").index($(this)) + 1;
    alert("Element poistion:" + barIndex);
});
```

I put an image to understand better:

[image]

Can you help me with an idea to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to achieve it. Here is how:

```
$("ul li").click(function (event) {
    var barIndex = $("ul li").index($(this));
    alert("Element poistion:" + barIndex);
    $(".dreapta").html('');
    $("ul li").eq(barIndex).find('img').clone().css({
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px' 
    }).appendTo('.dreapta');
});
```

Here is updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rtcydtyh/12/

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on a image the previous image will be removed and the new one will appear.

The css is also styled so the image will take the full div (height and width).

Code:

```
   var img;
$("ul li").click(function (event) {

    if (img !=undefined){
       $(img).remove();
    }
    var barIndex = $("ul li").index($(this)) + 1;
    alert("Element poistion:" + barIndex);
    var source= $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
    img.attr('src', source);
    img.appendTo('.dreapta');
});
```

and the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/rtcydtyh/15/

Answer (score 0):

A line as simple as this should do it:

```
$('div.dreapta').html( $('img', this).clone().height('100%').width('100%') );
```

```js
//CODE JS:

$("ul li").click(function (event) {
    //var barIndex = $("ul li").index($(this)) + 1;
    //alert("Element poistion:" + barIndex);
    $('div.dreapta').html( $('img', this).clone().height('100%').width('100%') );
});
```

```css
//CODE CSS:

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:95px;
    float:left;
}

ul li{border-bottom:1px solid;}

p{padding;0;margin:0;}

.dreapta{float:right;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://theimageconference.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/images-50x50.png"width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 1</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://whyfiles.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/promega_logo.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://bikechicago.com/wp-content/uploads/bikechicago-uber-image-C2.png" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 3</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://coordinate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/CBR_Web_Images.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 4</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://www.bpifrance-lelab.fr/var/bpi/storage/images/media/images/image-couverture/34625-1-fre-FR/image-couverture_large.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 5</p>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">
        <img src="http://odpiralnicasi.com/photos/012/539/image-big.jpg" width=50 height=50></img>
        <p>ELEMENT 6</p>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="dreapta">

</div>
```